# React(0.14.0)/Cordova app Crushing on Android 4.4.2 but working on Android 5+, can't figure the reason

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, reactjs

First of all, i need to say that the problem is that i don't know why the app is not working on Android 4.4.2, and due to my lack of experience in the platform and the absense of experts on this topic to ask them, my only options was to ask it here.

We tested the App in 4 Devices: Moto E (Android 5.0.2), Nexus 6. (Android 5.1.1), Azumi A50C (Android 4.4.2) and GEAR Feel 7005 B(Android 4.4.2), it worked correctly in the first 2, but didnt worked in the last 2 (it just showed the content in the index.html file, nothing about the React content).

We're using React(v0.14.0) to build it, with the following npm packages:

- "jquery": "^2.1.4"
- "nuka-carousel": "^1.0.1"
- "react": "^0.14.0"
- "react-dom": "^0.14.0"
- "react-addons-linked-state-mixin": "0.14.0"
- "react-googlemaps": "^0.4.0"
- "react-loader": "^1.4.0"
- "react-tappable": "^0.6.0"
- "underscore": "^1.7.0"

And cordova version 5.3.3 with the following plugins:

- cordova-plugin-android-support-v4 21.0.1 "Android Support v4"
- cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.3.0 "File Transfer"
- cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-vibration 1.2.0 "Vibration"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
- phonegap-plugin-push 1.3.0 "PushPlugin"

The app was working on Android 4.4.2 devices, but after a lot of changes testing with the 5+ ones, i tested it in the 4.4.2 devices to realize that it stopped working, and the changes are really relevant for the app so i cant just discard them.

As i said, there were a lot of changes, i tried to discover which of them broke the app for those devices, but i couldnt find out. I thought that probably changing from React 0.13.3 to 0.14.0 version could have caused the problem, but i returned to that version but nothing happened

So that is what i need to know, and if there's a solution for the problem.Here is the logcat of the app:

[Log File](http://tractorverde.cl/React/log_3.txt)
For your help and time, Thank you very much!

Comment: Please update your post and state what the issue is, because you did NOT state what the problem is. FWIW: sometime last week without warning Cordova moved the plugin server. You may need to reset your entire app from scratch, but maybe not, because you did not state what the issue is.

Comment: The issue is that the app is not working on Android 4.4.2 and i don't know why, that's what i need you to help me with, to find the reason for that

Comment: i usually delete the npm packages to compile the app and yesterday i deleted the android platform and rebuilt it from scratch, does that count as a reset?. Also, already did the updates so the post represents the problem  better

Comment: I can see you have a `white-list` problem already, but I do NOT know what you mean by *not working*. Please describe the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it. My partner was sending me wrong error logs so i was solving the wrong problem. The problem was a syntax error, somehow Android 5+ just didn't noticed it but Android 4.4.2 did.

Thank you very much for your help